# How to make IBAction do nothing until button pressed?

Tags: swift, ibaction

I am making a swift program that rolls die when a button is tapped but before that it asks them if they believe they will roll snake eyes, yes or no.

I want to know if its possible that when yes or no is tapped it will wait for the user to tap the roll button and then execute a response based on that? I am confused on how to add an IBAction pressed.

I have tried to add the yes button IBAction into the roll button IBAction and have ended up with many errors.

```
@IBAction func yesButton(_ sender: Any) {    
    if(diceImageView1.image == diceImageView2.image){
        resultText()
    } else {
        lossText()
        //functions changes label to message telling user if they rolled  snake eyes or not 
    }
}
```

I expect the user to be able to tap a response and then have to tap the roll button for the label to change.

Comment: Mocha's answer is exactly what you should be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Present a UIAlertViewController. Then do logic depending on the button.

See guide

https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/how-to-use-uialertcontroller-in-swift-70143d7fbede